# Обновить содержание RecyclerView заполненного через room, livedata с помощью spinner

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-spinner, android-room, livedata

Нужно в зависимости от выбора итема в spinner, изменять содержимое RecyclerView. Для заполнения RecyclerView использую architecture components. Устанавливаю observer.

Я не понимаю, что мне нужно сделать, когда выбираю итем в spinner'e. Если создавать новый слушатель, то я получаю новое содержание RecyclerView, но если изменять несколько раз, то можно заметить, что все мои слушатели (observers) реагируют на нажатия по итемам RecyclerView даже, если уже был создан новый.

Возможно нужно пересоздать фрагмент или заменить его как то, мой RecyclerView находится в tabbed activity.

Я не знаю как можно сделать запроск бд, чтобы получить другие данные и передать из слушателю, не устанавливав его или же как правильно изменить его.
Подскажите, что я могу сделать.

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); не помагает.

Мой фрагмент

```
public class AllSitesFragment extends Fragment implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


@BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@BindView(R.id.tvEmptyMessage)
TextView tvEmptyMessage;

@BindView(R.id.spinner)
Spinner spinner;

private WebSitesViewModel mWebSitesViewModel;
private MyRecViewAdapter adapter;

public AllSitesFragment() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_sites, container,  false);
ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
setHasOptionsMenu(true);

mWebSitesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WebSitesViewModel.class);

adapter = new MyRecViewAdapter(getContext(), mWebSitesViewModel, AllSitesFragment.this );
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

//Observer
mWebSitesViewModel.getAllWebSites().observe(this, new Observer<List<WebSites>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<WebSites> webSites) {
        adapter.setWebSites(webSites);


        if (adapter.getmWebSites().size() == 0) {
            tvEmptyMessage.setText(R.string.not_saved_sites);
            tvEmptyMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            tvEmptyMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
});

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


mWebSitesViewModel.getAllWebSites().removeObservers(getActivity());
return v;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
long id) {
switch (position) {
    case 0:

         // Refresh

        break;
    case 1:

         //Refresh

        break;

}
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```

Comment: что выбирается в спиннере, для новых данных нужна другая модель?

Comment: в зависимости от выбора спиннера, нужно делать разные запросы из бд

Comment: какие разные? @entity тоже разные?

Comment: Нет, с того же DAO взять другой метод.